# How do I build and install libfsapfs?

Tags: macos, command-line, install

I downloaded a tool from GitHub ([libfsapfs](https://github.com/libyal/libfsapfs)) to help with an issue I’m having with an external HDD formatted in APFS.

I have some familiarity with the terminal and know some basic Unix commands but struggling with installing this.

Edit: here is the full commands entered [with most of the install output removed]:

```
$ tar xfv libfsapfs-experimental-20220709.tar
$ cd libfsapfs-20220709
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-python --with-pyprefix
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... no
checking whether UID '501' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '20' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking build system type... aarch64-apple-darwin21.6.0
checking host system type... aarch64-apple-darwin21.6.0
checking how to print strings... printf
checking whether make supports the include directive... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/Daisy/Downloads/libfsapfs-20220709':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
$ make
xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-python --with-pyprefix
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
[lots of checking]…
configure: error: Unable to find python-config
$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
[Homebrew installed]…
$ brew install python
[Python installed]…
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-python --with-pyprefix
$ make install DESTDIR=$PWD/tmp
[installing]…
libtool: warning: '../libfsapfs/libfsapfs.la' has not been installed in '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/fsapfsinfo /Users/Daisy/Downloads/libfsapfs-20220709/tmp/usr/local/bin/fsapfsinfo
libtool: warning: '../libfsapfs/libfsapfs.la' has not been installed in '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/fsapfsmount /Users/Daisy/Downloads/libfsapfs-20220709/tmp/usr/local/bin/fsapfsmount
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
$ otool -LT tmp/usr/local/lib/libfsapfs.1.dylib
tmp/usr/local/lib/libfsapfs.1.dylib:
    /usr/local/lib/libfsapfs.1.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1311.100.3)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.11)
Table of contents (0 entries)
module index symbol index
$ cd tmp/usr/local/bin
$ ./fsapfsinfo
dyld[67019]: Library not loaded: '/usr/local/lib/libfsapfs.1.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/Daisy/Downloads/libfsapfs-20220709/tmp/usr/local/bin/fsapfsinfo'
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/libfsapfs.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libfsapfs.1.dylib' (no such file)
Abort trap: 6
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are following the wrong set of instructions. `make install DESTDIR=$PWD/tmp` is only required if you want to build a package, the files in `DESTDIR` can't be executed directly but need to be installed (via the package generated by `pkgbuild` in a later step).

To create and install a version for your own use, make sure all the dependencies are met and then follow the instructions in [Using GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)](https://github.com/libyal/libfsapfs/wiki/Building#using-gnu-compiler-collection-gcc):

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-python --with-pyprefix
make
sudo make install
```